# How can I get the count of entries in a structure?

Tags: structure

I'm using this in the root of a structure to try and get the count of entries in another part of the structure.

```
{% set count = craft.entries.section('hotelDetails').descendantOf('oakview-hotel').level(3).type('review').total() %}
        {{ count }}
```

But it's including entries from other hotels, I hoped descendantOf('oakview-hotel') would restrict the count to only oakview-hotel. When I replace escendantOf('oakview-hotel') with descendantOf(17) 17 being the ID oakview-hotel the count is restricted to oakview-hotel and the entry count is correct.

Ca anyone please telly me why descendantOf('oakview-hotel') isn't working for me or suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There may be a better option, but off the top of my head, you could do:

```
{% set countParent = craft.entries.slug('oakview-hotel').first() %}
{% set count = craft.entries.section('hotelDetails').descendantOf(countParent).level(3).type('review').total() %}
        {{ count }}
```

Answer (score 2):

[descendantOf](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#descendantOf) accepts either an EntryModel object or an entry’s ID. And you are passing it a string that isn't the id, so that's why it isn't working