# descendantOf() parameter, entryModel or ID?

Tags: entries, structure, descendantof

I'm confused about what to pass as a parameter in the descendantOf() function.
I'm developing a website and passing an entry ID as a string (I also tested it as an integer) and everything went fine, untill now. Suddenly, when I try to use it with new template code, that doesn't work anymore. It does however still work in my template I wrote last week.

The [docs say](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.categories#descendantOf) that the parameter has to be an EntryModel:

> descendantOf #
>
> Only fetch categories that are a descendant of a given category.
>   Accepts a CategoryModel object.

In [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1298/how-can-i-get-the-count-of-entries-in-a-structure) on SE, someone says it can be an Entry ID.

> descendantOf accepts either an EntryModel object or an entry’s ID.

However, if I use the next code (category is not a category group, I'm using a structure for it) where `currentRegionId` is an entryId as a string or integer:

```
{% for productCategory in product.productCategory.descendantOf(currentRegionId).order("title asc").find() %}
```

This works. But according to the docs, it shouldn't work, because I'm passing an ID and not an EntryModel.

It also works when I pass that ID while using eager loading:

```
{% set mainCategories = craft.entries({
    section:            'productCategories',
    level:              2,
    descendantOf:       currentRegionId,
    limit:              null,
    with:               ['productCategoryIcon']
}) %}
```

However, if I try the next piece of code in another template:

```
{% for category in entry.applyToCategories if category.descendantOf(currentRegionId) %}
```

I get this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Craft\BaseElementModel::isDescendantOf() must be
>   an instance of Craft\BaseElementModel, integer given

If I pass an EntryModel it does work as expected and according with the docs:

```
{% for category in entry.applyToCategories if category.descendantOf(craft.entries.id(currentRegionId).first()) %}
```

So what's going on? Is it something with the way I fetch my entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different things.

```
{% set entries = myEntryModel.myEntriesField.descendantOf(var) %}
```

In this case the Entries field returns an `ElementCriteriaModel` object and you are setting the [`descendantOf`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#descendantOf) parameter, which does in fact accept `EntryModel` objects or an Entry ID as an integer value. The Craft documentation is incomplete in this regard.

```
{% set bool = myEntryModel.isDescendantOf(var) %}
```

Here you are using the method [`isDescendantOf`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#isDescendantOf) that is available for an `EntryModel` and returns whether the entry is a descendant of another entry. This method apparently only accepts an `EntryModel`.

Comment: Looks like a solid explanation! Thanks. That'll be it I guess.